# Getting an error message when running sudo apt update command

Tags: apt, updates

keep getting an error when trying to update

```
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 59min 8s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 59min 48s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 58min 39s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-proposed/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 59min 40s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

Comment: Manually set your system time to the current time and date in your time/date settings.  You've got a time desync on your system that is breaking updates.

Comment: did that still getting errors<pre><font color="#CC0000"><b>E: </b></font>Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 11466 (apt-get)
<font color="#C4A000">N: </font>Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
<font color="#CC0000"><b>E: </b></font>Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
</pre>